# What document-id do you use to save user data anonymously to firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Imagine an app that is saving the user's configuration to Firebase. The structure in Firestore looks like:

```
users (collection)
  - user1 (document)
  - user2 (document)
```

How do you name the user's document, in a way that keeps the user anonymous?

My original intention was to use `User.uid` as document-id. This would make identifying a person very difficult compared to using the email address. Might appear over-cautious, but you never know if the database gets hacked, and if it would happen and there would be plenty of personal data in it, then well, with the current regulations, you're pretty much... "screwed".

Problem with `User.uid` is, that it changes every time the app is installed, so all data would get lost...

How do you save user data anonymously, so it's available across installations but does not allow an unauthorized third party to figure out the user's identity?

Comment: You can either have anonymous authentication, or survive app reinstalls, not both. Aside from that, using UIDs as document IDs is fairly idiomatic, and I'm not sure I understand the security concern you're trying to address. It might help if you focus on a specific threat to the data, and show what you've done to secure it already.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. An app-specific user id, that is unique for each app but also stays the same across app installations, would be useful. Sure we can implement it our self by scrambling the user's email address, but implementing this in a secure manner is getting complicated...  Makes me wonder how other developers ensure that their user's data stays anonymous at Firebase.

Comment: Agreed that a consistent UID is useful, which is why Firebase offers those for all providers except anonymous ones. To be able to generate the same UID upon a re-install it must know something about the user that identifies them, like the email address in your last comment. If that is an acceptable requirement for your use-case, you can use the email+password or email-link provider.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of Firestore you can do this by using the method [push](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-push) which ensures a unique and chronological key.